# How to get JQuery to perform the same action as a html form

Tags: jquery, forms, get

I'm having trouble trying to get JQuery perform the same action a form would perform. I have the following form which works exactly as I want:

```
<form method='get' action='/editor'>
  <input name='r'>
  <input name='c'>
  <input name='t'>
  <input type='submit'>
</form>
```

The handler on the servor for /editor simply redirects the page with the r, c & t parameters in the url. This works exactly as I want it too.

Now, I'm trying to do exactly the same thing but with JQuery, this is what I have so far:

```
$.get("/editor", { r: "foo", c: "bar", t: "meow" } );
```

The request is sent as can be seen from the console log: **XHR finished loading** but the page is not redirected to /editor

My question is how can I perform exactly the same function as the html form but in JQuery?

Thank you all for you help :)

Comment: So you want to have the exact same behaviour as an HTML form would normally? Why not just use an HTML form normally?

Comment: Because the information I want to send is stored in Javascript variables. The user does not enter them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to redirect to `/editor` yourself.  If you want to do exactly what the form does normally including redirect, there's really no point in having JavaScript do it at all.  However, since you asked:

```
$.get(/* what you have */).done(function () { window.location = '/editor'; });
```

Comment: I can't do this because I need the Handler on GAE to redirect to /editor inorder to send further information

Comment: What is "the Handler on GAE?"  So do you want to redirect to /editor or not?

Comment: Actually I could just do window.location = '/editor?r=' + r + '&c=" + c + "&t=" + t  then I won't need to go to the server. Thanks I never knew about window.location

Answer (score 0):

Just for the record, you can also give the input elements a value via Javascript, and then:

```
document.forms["id_of_the_form"].submit();
```

Maybe it's more elegant.